# Rails Paperclip for both PDF and Image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, paperclip

I wanted to make user able to upload either PDF or image . I know only for handling image is there anyway to handle both image and pdf?

I can do up to here

Inside Post Model:

```
  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => {:content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
```

In console:

```
bin/rails g paperclip post attachment
```

If it is image then i can do this in view

```
=image_tag post.image.url(:medium)  
# It is haml syntax
```

But how do i display download link if it is pdf or let say word file?

Answer (score 0):

Use :original instead of :medium if it's not an image. You probably need to overwrite the detected MIME type for newer word formats since they are detected as zip files.

Comment: What should i write in view file?

Comment: Is there anyway to check if it is image and it is not image ?

Comment: well, you could use path to find out if it exists, or use mimetype check such as in, 

   def image?
      !(file_content_type =~ /^image\/.*/).nil?
   end

Can't figure out how to make code block of that...